# custom compile an egg and install console scripts

Tags: buildout

I'm trying to get the following buildout working. The buildout is meant to be self contained so I don't want to install any system packages

```
[s3ql]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
eggs =
    ${s3ql-build:egg}

[s3ql-build]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = s3ql
find-links =
   https://bitbucket.org/nikratio/s3ql/downloads/s3ql-1.18.1.tar.bz2#egg=s3ql-1.18.1
   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/s3ql/s3ql_1.16.orig.tar.bz2#egg=s3ql
   https://github.com/wilkinson/s3ql/archive/master.zip#egg=s3ql
   https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw/releases/download/3.8.4.3-r1/apsw-3.8.4.3-r1.zip
include-dirs =
    ${liblzma:location}/include
    ${sqlite:location}/include
library-dirs =
    ${liblzma:location}/lib
    ${sqlite:location}/lib
rpath =
    ${liblzma:location}/lib
    ${sqlite:location}/lib

[liblzma]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.0.5.tar.gz

[pysqlite]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = pysqlite
include-dirs = ${sqlite:location}/include
library-dirs = ${sqlite:location}/lib
rpath = ${sqlite:location}/lib

[sqlite]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080403.tar.gz
```

and I get the following

```
Updating liblzma.
Updating sqlite.
Updating s3ql-build.
Installing s3ql.
Getting distribution for 'pyliblzma>=0.5.3'.
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
In file included from src/liblzma.c:1:0:
src/liblzma.h:24:18: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: 
command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occurred when trying to install pyliblzma 0.5.3. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
   Installing s3ql.
   Getting distribution for 'pyliblzma>=0.5.3'.
Error: Couldn't install: pyliblzma 0.5.3
```

It seems like it tries to compile it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. Yes using a combination of zc.recipe.egg:scripts and zc.recipe.egg:custom is the right approach. But it's confusing as zc.recipe.egg:custom doesn't build the dependencies so it appears like it wasn't picking up the built s3ql.

Here is the solution that built for me.

```
[s3ql]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
eggs =
    ${pyliblzma:egg}
    ${llfuse:egg}
    ${apsw:egg}
    ${s3ql-build:egg}    

[s3ql-build]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = s3ql
find-links =
   https://bitbucket.org/nikratio/s3ql/downloads/s3ql-1.18.1.tar.bz2#egg=s3ql-1.18.1
# need this patch to build on osx
# https://bitbucket.org/nikratio/s3ql/commits/39352e8e4cb48521dd9ff589e93fc2e4ae390f9d/raw/
include-dirs =
    ${liblzma:location}/include
    ${sqlite:location}/include
library-dirs =
    ${liblzma:location}/lib
    ${sqlite:location}/lib
rpath =
    ${liblzma:location}/lib
    ${sqlite:location}/lib

[pyliblzma]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = pyliblzma
include-dirs = ${liblzma:location}/include
library-dirs = ${liblzma:location}/lib
rpath = ${liblzma:location}/lib

[llfuse]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = llfuse
# NOTE: requires apt-get install libfuse-dev pkg-config libattr1-dev
# fuse has to go into the kernal so we can't compile it into the buildout


[apsw]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = apsw
find-links =
   https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw/releases/download/3.8.4.3-r1/apsw-3.8.4.3-r1.zip
# includes, libraries etc is ignored by apsw setup.py
environment = apsw-env
[apsw-env]
CPPFLAGS= -I${sqlite:location}/include -I${liblzma:location}/lib
LDFLAGS= -L${sqlite:location}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${sqlite:location}/lib -L${liblzma:location}/include -Wl,-rpath=${liblzma:location}/lib
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${sqlite:location}/lib/pkgconfig:${liblzma:location}/lib/pkgconfig



[liblzma]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.0.5.tar.gz

[sqlite]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080403.tar.gz
```

Comment: "But it's confusing as zc.recipe.egg:custom doesn't build the dependencies so it appears like it wasn't picking up the built s3ql." - Question your assumption! What did you expect, what happened? You use zc.recipe.egg:custom in 4 buildout parts. Which part do you mean?

Comment: s3ql-build in the original question doesn't install dependencies. In this case most of the dependencies also need to be custom compiled to resulting in buildout you see above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install liblzma-dev on your OS.

```
gottfried@dell-xt2:~/virtualenvs/liblzma$ sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  liblzma-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liblzma-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 159 kB of archives.
After this operation, 645 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main liblzma-dev amd64 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu1 [159 kB]
Fetched 159 kB in 1s (111 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package liblzma-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 272326 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking liblzma-dev:amd64 (from .../liblzma-dev_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up liblzma-dev:amd64 (5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu1) ...

gottfried@dell-xt2:~/virtualenvs/liblzma$ bin/easy_install pyliblzma
Searching for pyliblzma
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyliblzma/
Best match: pyliblzma 0.5.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyliblzma/pyliblzma-0.5.3.tar.bz2#md5=500f61116ee1ab4063b49c121786863a
Processing pyliblzma-0.5.3.tar.bz2
Writing /tmp/easy_install-kAg4nj/pyliblzma-0.5.3/setup.cfg
Running pyliblzma-0.5.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-kAg4nj/pyliblzma-0.5.3/egg-dist-tmp-TmcZm_
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding pyliblzma 0.5.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/gottfried/virtualenvs/liblzma/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyliblzma-0.5.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for pyliblzma
Finished processing dependencies for pyliblzma
```

Comment: Sorry I should have said that the whole point is to avoid installing system packages since I want to deploy this to many places.